# Angular is printing the route, instead of rendering the partial in the view

Tags: angularjs, angular-routing

I have my app set up with a `$routeProvider` as:

```
angular.module('myApp', [])

    .config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider){
        $routeProvider
            .when('/authorisation', { template: 'templates/authorisation.html', controller: AuthenticationController})
            .otherwise('templates/404.html');
    }]);
```

My `index.html` is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="myApp">
<head>
    <title>Gift Cloud Dash</title>
    <script src="lib\angular\angular.js"></script>

    <!-- App config -->
    <script src="js\app.js"></script>

    <!-- Import controllers -->
    <script src="js\controllers\authentication-controller.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div>
    <a href="#/authorisation">Authorisation</a>
</div>
<div ng-view></div>
</body>
</html>
```

When I open the index page, I see the hyperlink, but when I click it the file path is displayed rather than it being rendered in the `<div ng-view></div>`.

[image: Angular displaying resourse path.]

Comment: Use `templateUrl`, not `template`

Comment: Cheers, not sure there I got that from!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fixed it, I'll leave it here in case anyone else gets the same symptoms:

The syntax in my routing config is wrong:  It should be:

```
angular.module('myApp', [])

    .config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider){
        $routeProvider
            .when('/authorisation', { templateUrl: 'templates/authorisation.html', controller: AuthenticationController})
            .otherwise({redirectTo: 'templates/404.html'});
    }]);
```